# Why OnItemClick invoking while calling on notifyDataSetChanged() in Spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a problem while updating spinner adapter. I have a spinner when onItem Click of spinner i have update the TextView. Whenever i have update the spinner list by calling adapet.notifyDataSetChanged() the onItemSelected Lisener automatically invoking without selecting the spinner. why its happening? I have shared some peace of code here

**This is for updating adapter with list**

```
 if(mEmailList == null){
   mEmailList = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
 mEmailList.clear();
 for(int i =0 ; i < responseArray.length() ; i++){
   responseObj = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String collected_email = "";
   collected_email = Utils.getDataFromJSON(responseObj, "eMail");
   if(Utils.isHavingValue(collected_email.trim())){
      mEmailList.add(collected_email);
    }
  }
  if(emailAdapter != null){
      if(mActivity != null){
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            emailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
       });
   }
}
```

and this is onItenSelectionListener

```
if(mEmail_spinner != null && emailAdapter != null){
   mEmail_spinner.setAdapter(emailAdapter);
   mEmail_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
      Log.d(TAG, "On ItemSelect called Adapter = "+arg0+"    View = "+arg1+" value "+arg2);
      if(Utils.isHavingValue(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString())){
     if(mEmailReg != null){
       mEmailReg.setText(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(
    AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "On Nothing selected called Adapter = "+arg0);
    if(mEmailReg != null){
    //   mEmailReg.setText(mPreviousText);
        }
   });
}
```

never the notifyDataSetChanged() is called the List ItemClickListener alson called. how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mEmail_spinner.setAdapter(emailAdapter);
```

to

```
mEmail_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
mEmail_spinner.setAdapter(emailAdapter);
```

In this way if you have assigned an `OnItemSelectedListener` to `mEmail_spinner` it won't be called when you call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Set the `onItemSelectedListener` again after you call `setAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the Adapter is updated. The old items are gone, the new items are added, so the spinner has a new selected item. That is why the onItemClick method is called.